# Roasting sirloin which has already been cut into slices

Tags: beef, roast-beef

I was intending to cook roast beef with a joint of sirloin, but unfortunately my wife has returned from the supermarket with the sirloin already cut into slices (it wasn't her fault, and I don't know why the butcher sliced the meat). My question is: would it still be possible to roast the sirloin as if it were one joint or should I try a different cooking method?

Comment: how thick are the slices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sirloin is a better steak than a roast, but if that is what you want...

Sear the cut surfaces in a hot pan, and then quickly assemble it into a roast block and twine/skewer it together. Don't go crazy, it is never going to be perfect

Roast as normal, baste a little more often than normal, and maybe trim a few minutes off the time

Now the fun with this is that you can flavour the slices before assembly, garlic, herbs, what ever you like. It's like having a stuffed roast, but already in serving portions. Many people cut pockets into their roast to stuff/flavour it, now you have it done in a large scale

Comment: All's well that ends well: my wife went back to the supermarket, complained, cried a little - and was rewarded with the butcher taking back the sliced meat and promising to give us a bigger joint. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 3):

You could try tying it up into the original shape, but the trouble is that you've got cut surfaces which have been exposed to bacteria, and which will not reach a high enough temperature to kill them  unless you're going to cook it to death, so I wouldn't recommend this. It seems you've actually got sirloin steaks, so why not just cook them as such?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too - if the slices are thick, then I'll grill them. If they're thin, I'll do a stir fry - which seems like a terrific waste of expensive meat.